# ng-bootstrap tooltip not showing up on position right

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I've an angular app, wherein in the menu drawer im trying to use ng-bootstrap's tooltip. Now this renders perfectly fine in case of `position=bottom` or `position=top`. Whilst trying to use position right the tooltip isnt showing at all. I tried deleting various components (thought the z-index might be a issue here) and even on stand alone case this still isnt showing up. The screenshot below will explain my case even further.

Screenshot --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/KySvR.png

Versions -->  "@angular/core": "7.1.4",  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.3.1"

````
<div class="menu-item" placement="right" ngbTooltip="Tooltip contents" >
....
</div>```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can try add this attribute to your menu-items

```
data-toggle="tooltip"
```

Comment: data-toggle isnt the issue here, its the position issue, please see the screenshot in which you can see the tooltip is being generated, but doesnt shows up.